# How can I install PSD Importer from Unity Packages?

Tags: unity-game-engine, psd

In Unity Packages there is a tool to import PSD files: https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.2d.psdimporter@1.2/manual/index.html

But I can't find this package in my Unity Package Manager (Window -> Package Manager).

How can I install it?..

Currently using Unity 2019.1.0f2 if matters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PSD Importer is still in `Preview` state (see [Packages documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PackagesList.html)).

→ You have to enable <kbd>Show Preview Packages</kbd> in the <kbd>Advanced</kbd> menu of the `PackageManager` window

[image]